# Unable to withdraw/send ETH from shapeshift app. Need advise on what to do, it pops up the message "Invalid BigNumber String Argument"

Tags: wallets, ethereum-wallet-dapp, bitcoin, shapeshift

[image]

Having trouble sending out et here um from my shapeshift mobile app. Its over two weeks now but I'm still not able to send or withdraw my ethereum.

Comment: Please I need advise on what to do

Comment: From the error message it seems to be an application bug. Did you try contacting shapeshift customer support?

Comment: I already did but no positive response so far